# How to write a struct to a pre existing byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, serialization, buffer

I've seen lots of examples of how to convert a struct to a byte array by creating a new byte array.

But i am trying to avoid this. I have a message buffer of byte[1024] and i want to write my struct to this byte array from index 1 onwards. Index 0 is the header so i skip that one.

I can't find any examples of this is done without creating a new byte array. Is this even possible ?

How i currently convert objects to byte arrays:

```
    public static byte[] GetBytes<T>(T data)
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(data);
        byte[] arr = new byte[size];
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(data, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        return arr;
    }
```

The problem with this is its writing the object on a new array at index 0. I need to apply it to index 1 onwards. Where index 0 will designate the size of struct in bytes.

Comment: If you want to use an existing byte array rather than creating a new one then pass in the existing byte array and use it. What problem are you having using it?

Comment: Which serialization API are you using? Which examples? There is no canonical way to convert an arbitrary struct into a byte array, so answers might be all over place unless you constrain the question with more information or a specific example.

Comment: Will you please show the code you're using to create a new byte array?

Comment: I will add code example of my current marshal.

Comment: @Servy my pre existing empty byte array is 1024 bytes long i don't know how to write a struct to it, hence the purpose of the question. I only know how to do so from a new byte array at index 0.

Comment: @Sir So you know how to construct a new byte array, and then write out the data to that newly constructed byte array, but you don't know how to write out to a byte array that was already constructed, even though you know how to write out the data to an array that you just constructed.

Comment: @Servy i need it to assign the length of the struct's byte array to index 0 then the actual byte array of the struct from index 1 onwards. That part i am unsure of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your existing code as an example, in order to copy your struct bytes to an existing array at position 1, just pass the existing array and the start position of `1` to `Marshal.Copy`:

```
byte[] existingArray = new byte[1024];      // This is your existing 1024 size byte array

int size = Marshal.SizeOf(data);
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

Marshal.StructureToPtr(data, ptr, true);
Marshal.Copy(ptr, existingArray, 1, size);  // Pass your array and start at position 1
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);]
```